# Is number of compiled modules affecting size of kernel in RAM?

Tags: kernel

When I am compiling a kernel myself, the amount of drivers and modules I compile is definitely affecting the size of produced binary.

Does compiling the kernel also affect the size of kernel when it loads into memory?

I mean, when I compile also drivers I don't need for my hardware, will kernel just ignore them, or are they also loaded in RAM?

TL/DR:
The question definitely is: when I compile kernel A containing **only** drivers that I need and kernel B containing drivers I need + extra drivers I don't, will kernel B eat more memory than kernel A?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that with external modules (eg `make menuconfig` shows `M`), you'll only see more memory usage if you load the module. And that's all frightfully dynamic these days.

But yes, built-in modules will probably use more memory.

Don't forget that you can create a config based on the modules you're currently using with `make localmodconfig`. I've always had a bit of a battle with it personally but it's there to strip kernels right down to what you need. There's [a good article on h-online](http://www.h-online.com/open/features/Good-and-quick-kernel-configuration-creation-1403046.html) on kernel trimming.

Comment: Sounds good, nice link... just not sure about the "probably" part :-) I was also thinking that it "probably" uses more memory, just wanted to make sure if yes or no